# Pygame Cannot Blit Individual Items In A List In A For Loop ||| Err(Invalid Destination For Blit)

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a small little game and I'm having a problem here in the homecoming stretch. Really, all I need to do is blit this list to an image.

myList is comprised of brick.get_rect()

```
   # myList = myCollider(myList, ballRect)
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if(ballRect.colliderect(myList[i])):
            print("ok")
            del myList[i]

    #for i in range(0, len(myList)):

     #   screen.blit(brick, myList[i])
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        screen.blit(brick, myList[i])

    screen.blit(platform, platformRectangle)
    screen.blit(ball, ballRect)
```

Additionally, all the code works until I add this

```
del myList[i]
```

The code works if I remove it, and activates at collisions, like I want, but for some reason this doesn't seem to work.

Why won't it blit my list?

In addition, the game works until the defined collision happens and del myList[i] is activated.

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jackson\source\repos\C200-Breakout-Team26\JackCrap\EXT.py", line 152, in <module>
    Play(400, 400, black, 1)
  File "C:\Users\Jackson\source\repos\C200-Breakout-Team26\JackCrap\EXT.py", line 129, in Play
    if(ballRect.colliderect(myList[i])):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot)

Comment: What do you expect `screen.blit(brick, myList[i])` to do if `myList[i]` is an empty list?

Comment: why do you add `myList[i] = []` ? `get_rect()` returns instance of class `Rect()` which is used to draw. Now you try to draw `screen.blit(brick, [])`

Comment: So I had been playing around with some ideas and that was the last one i tried. Previously, I had tried to delete spot in the list. Ill update it with the deletetion code.

Comment: BTW: deleting in loop makes problem because when you delete element then it moves other elements in this place but `for` doesn't know it and it skip one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove element from list then you should use `del myList[i]` but it makes problem when you use it inside `for` loop so better create list for elements which you have to keep.

```
keep = []

for item in myList:
    if ballRect.colliderect(item):
        print("ok")
    else:
        keep.append(item)

myList = keep

for item in myList:
    screen.blit(brick, item)
```

---

**EDIT:** removing elements using list comprehension

```
myList = [item for item in myList if not ballRect.colliderect(item)]
```

---

**EDIT:** see doc for [Sprite](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html)

If you will keep elements in [pygame.sprite.Group()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) then you can use [pygame.sprite.spritecollide](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) to check collision between ball and all bricks and automatically remove bricks.

But `bricks` and `ball` have to be classes with `self.rect`

```
pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ball_sprite, block_sprites_group, True)
```

Comment: I add the same as list comprehension but it can't print `"ok"`.